# Why won't JS fire on ubercart checkout page and how do I fix?

Tags: ubercart, javascript

I need some custom JS (jQuery to be precise) to run on ubercart's  `/cart/checkout` page. I turned off JS optimization and tried adding it to several different files that are already loading and the JS never fires. It is in the page as if I view-source I can search and find it. I did put $(document).ready(... so it should be waiting for the page to load before running. If I run the same JS from the console of firefox or chrome it does exactly what it's supposed to do. The JS files are all loaded with `drupal_add_js()`.

My only solution at this point is the make a block that only contains that JS and only shows on that page, which it not an optimum solution, but will probably work. Anything else I'm missing on this though?

Comment: Did end up adding a block that shows only on that page which does the JS/JQuery and it did work, but still interested if anybody has another, better, solution.

Comment: Would you please post an answer with the solution that you found.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I came up with for this was to create a `block`, assign a `blocktheme` and in the `tpl.php` file put the `JS`. Then assign the block to only show on that page. Bit of a work-around, but it did work.